# Is it possible to aggregate lists in a groupby to a list and not a list of lists in polars? (ie: sum/extend lists instead of listing them)

Tags: python, python-polars

I am using polars (version "0.15.14") on python 3.10.

I have this type of data:

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "Case": ["case1", "case1"],
        "List": [["x1", "x2"], ["x3", "x4"]],
    }
)
```

I would like to group them so that the lists are added to each other (like the `.extend` function for python lists).

I tried to flatten the lists after the groupby but it is extremely slow and if there are too many rows my computer (macOs M1) simply crashes so it is not scalable. (I work with millions of rows). See code below:

```
df.groupby("Case").agg(
        [
            pl.col("List")
        ]
    ).with_columns(
                [
                    pl.col("List").arr.eval(pl.element().explode()),
                ],
            )
```

Is there a simpler and/or more efficient way to do this?

I would expect that something like this:

```
df.groupby("Case").agg(
        [
            pl.col("List").sum_list()
        ]
    )
```

would give me in a reasonable time and in a scalable way:

```
shape: (1, 2)
┌───────┬────────────────────────┐
│ Case  ┆ List                   │
│ ---   ┆ ---                    │
│ str   ┆ list[str]              │
╞═══════╪════════════════════════╡
│ case1 ┆ ["x1", "x2", ... "x4"] │
└───────┴────────────────────────┘
```

FYI: this equivalent in pandas is pretty straight forward:

```
df.groupby("Case").agg(sum)
```

as pandas handle the sum of lists. Its performance are not suited for my case though.

**UPDATE:** after creating an issue here: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/6188 The solution seems to be to use the str.concat function instead of working with lists as far as I understood.

Comment: can you link the solution with str.concat?

Comment: @DariuszKrynicki Just added an answer to my question with some example code

Comment: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/6188

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75678741/polars-aggregate-arraystring-column-into-setstr/75685820?noredirect=1#comment133555963_75685820

Answer (score 4):

This would give you your expected output:

```py
In [4]: df.groupby('Case').agg(pl.col('List').explode())
Out[4]:
shape: (1, 2)
┌───────┬────────────────────────┐
│ Case  ┆ List                   │
│ ---   ┆ ---                    │
│ str   ┆ list[str]              │
╞═══════╪════════════════════════╡
│ case1 ┆ ["x1", "x2", ... "x4"] │
└───────┴────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: thanks for the answer @ignoring_gravity! I tried that before and this makes my computer crash if the dataframe is too big (same way as I mentioned in my question with the with_column)! Maybe I'll open an issue directly on polars repo then

Answer (score 2):

After discussing the issue on polars repo: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/6188 here is an example of code that would do the trick using string concatenation:

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "Case": ["case1", "case1"],
        "List": ["x1, x2", "x3, x4"], # shape your data as seperated string
    }).groupby("Case").agg([
            pl.col("List").str.concat(", ") # use the concat fonction with your seperator
           ]).with_column(pl.col("List").str.split(", ")) # split to get a list
```

So just concatenate strings all the way and then split the strings based on the used separator. This won't create memory nor time overload. It is not a perfect solution as it is kind of specific but works for me at least.

Answer (score 1):

```
df
    .with_columns([
        pl.col("List").arr.join(",")
    ])
    .groupby(["Case"])
    .agg([
        pl.col("List").alias("List")
    ])
    .with_columns([
        pl.col("List").arr.join(",")
    ])
    .with_columns([
        pl.col("List").str.split(",").arr.unique().alias("List")
    ])
```