# polars aggregate array[string] column into set[str]

Tags: python, set, aggregate, flatten, python-polars

I have polars dataframe:

```
df = pl.DataFrame({
    'col1': [["aaa", "aaa"], ["bbb", "ccc"], ["ccc", "ddd", "ddd"], ["ddd", "ddd", "ddd"]],
    'col2': ["a", "a", "a", "a"],
    'col3': ["x", "x", "y", "y"]
})
```

I want to groupby col2, col3 and aggregate col1 into Set[String]

```
(df
.groupby(["col2", "col3"])
.agg([pl.col("col1").flatten().apply(set).alias("result")])
)
```

when I run it on 17 milion records then it performs very slow.
after 10minutes it still does not complete.

how to speed it up?

EDIT:

This is how I solved it and it is blazing fast:

```
df = (
    df
    .with_columns([
        pl.col("col1").arr.join(",")
    ])
    .groupby(["col2", "col3"])
    .agg([
        pl.col("col1").alias("col1")
    ])
    .with_columns([
        pl.col("col1").arr.join(",")
    ])
    .with_columns([
        pl.col("col1").str.split(",").arr.unique().alias("col1")
    ])
)

┌──────┬──────┬───────────────────────┐
│ col2 ┆ col3 ┆ col1                  │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---                   │
│ str  ┆ str  ┆ list[str]             │
╞══════╪══════╪═══════════════════════╡
│ a    ┆ x    ┆ ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"] │
│ a    ┆ y    ┆ ["ccc", "ddd"]        │
└──────┴──────┴───────────────────────┘
```

Comment: please see edited question EDIT section for the final solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the final solution I came with: it uses polars native functions and it blazing fast.

preprocess with join array[str] column into string with separator >> aggregate string column into array[string] >> postprocess: first repeat join array[str] column into string with separator so then split string on the separator and get unique values.

```
df = (
       df
       .with_columns([
           pl.col("col1").arr.join(",")
       ])
       .groupby(["col2", "col3"])
       .agg([
           pl.col("col1").alias("col1")
       ])
       .with_columns([
            pl.col("col1").arr.join(",")
       ])
       .with_columns([
           pl.col("col1").str.split(",").arr.unique().alias("col1")
       ])
   )
```

this is the output:

```
┌──────┬──────┬───────────────────────┐
│ col2 ┆ col3 ┆ col1                  │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---                   │
│ str  ┆ str  ┆ list[str]             │
╞══════╪══════╪═══════════════════════╡
│ a    ┆ x    ┆ ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"] │
│ a    ┆ y    ┆ ["ccc", "ddd"]        │
└──────┴──────┴───────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you, but unfortunately my input strings may have commas and any other character. I'm hoping there is a way that doesn't require string joining and splitting...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need sets but only a unification of the elements then you could try to use [`.unique()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.unique.html) instead of `.apply(set)`:

```py
result = (
    df.groupby(["col2", "col3"])
    .agg([pl.col("col1").flatten().unique().alias("result")])
)
```

Result for the sample:

```
┌──────┬──────┬───────────────────────┐
│ col2 ┆ col3 ┆ result                │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---                   │
│ str  ┆ str  ┆ list[str]             │
╞══════╪══════╪═══════════════════════╡
│ a    ┆ y    ┆ ["ccc", "ddd"]        │
│ a    ┆ x    ┆ ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"] │
└──────┴──────┴───────────────────────┘
```

I did a `timeit`-benchmarking with larger dataframes (up to 100,000 rows) and this version was consistently about 10 times faster.

Comment: I does not make such difference at my end. I have tried all three approaches:                           
  pl.col("col1").arr.explode().unique().alias("result")  
  pl.col("col1").flatten().unique().alias("result")  
 pl.col("col1").flatten().apply(set).alias("result")   and I terminate each case after 10 min 
 of executing as it is too long for me. I expect it to complete in 2 min.

Comment: @DariuszKrynicki Interesting! Could it be that the dataframe has a relatively large number of groups? In this case I found `result = df.explode("col1").unique().groupby(["col2", "col3"]).agg(pl.col("col1").alias("result"))` to be more efficient.

Comment: col1 is heavily skewed when I check col1 len. The mean is ~17 while max is 200 000.

Comment: My example is just test sample as in practice I have 15 cols so explode will blow out data a bit but I will test tomorrow.

Comment: I also find the agg without flatten so agg of array [str] column into array[array[string]] nested column is blazing fast. It is just the flatten that is not free.

Comment: I also find this but see no solution for array as string concat https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75084875/is-it-possible-to-aggregate-lists-in-a-groupby-to-a-list-and-not-a-list-of-lists

Comment: ok, I solved it. please see answer in the EDIT section of the question.

Comment: @DariuszKrynicki Nice! You should post it as an answer (I will upvote).